# Update positions in subset of sorted vector

Tags: c++, sorting, subset, stdvector

I am working on a problem in C++ that involves calculations on arrays of objects sorted along different attributes. Suppose I have an array of 5 objects with 3 different attributes (A, B, and C), and I sort the array according to each attribute individually. This gives me three arrays that tell me for each object where its position would be if I were to sort them along the corresponding attribute.

```
std::vector<int> A_Order = { 1, 3, 0, 2, 4 };
std::vector<int> B_Order = { 2, 4, 3, 1, 0 };
std::vector<int> C_Order = { 0, 2, 4, 3, 1 };
```

Now I want to split the objects into 2 subsets, always picking a position N in one of the orderings, where all objects at position `x <= N` go into the first subset, and all `x > N` go into the next subset. If I do this on attribute A at `N = 2`, I get the following:

```
std::vector<int> A_OrderSub0 = { 1, 0, 2 };
std::vector<int> B_OrderSub0 = { 2, 3, 1 };
std::vector<int> C_OrderSub0 = { 0, 4, 3 };

std::vector<int> A_OrderSub1 = { 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> B_OrderSub1 = { 4, 0 };
std::vector<int> C_OrderSub1 = { 2, 1 };
```

To perform the next iteration of calculations efficiently, I once again need the subsets to be ordered along the attributes and get the resulting positions (in the example above, I need `B_OrderSub1 = { 4, 0 }` to become `B_OrderSub1 = { 1, 0 }`). What is the most efficient way for me to reuse the "global positions", which I only have to get once at the start, to then get the "locally ordered positions" for the objects each time I split them into subsets?

Comment: Have you considered [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) to partition the vectors on the index?  Then you don't need to create new vectors -- just use the returned iterator that `partition` gives you.

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand how 0 gets to be place in `B_OrderSub1` when it is clearly on the low end of the scale.  Also, is `N` zero-based?

Comment: N is zero-based. 0 moves to the second subset because we are splitting along A. In this context, I always consider one attribute at a time for a split. So in the example, I choose the objects for the first subset based on whether their index in the A-ordering is below 3 (it doesn't matter what their order is in B or C, and I can still tell what their relative ordering would be based on the position information they have from the original sorting)